# AWS S3 cli - tag all objects within a directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

Is there a way to apply a tag (or set of tags) to all objects in an S3 directory using one single [put-object-tagging](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-object-tagging.html) cli command?

I.e if I have two files (`test0.txt`, `test.txt`) I can do the run the following two commands:

```
>aws s3api put-object-tagging --bucket mybucket --key foo/bar/test0.txt --tagging 'TagSet=[{Key=colour,Value=blue}]'
>aws s3api put-object-tagging --bucket mybucket --key foo/bar/test1.txt --tagging 'TagSet=[{Key=colour,Value=blue}]'
```

When trying to pass the folder itself as the --key option I get the following error (as it must reference a single object):

```
>aws s3api put-object-tagging --bucket mybucket --key foo/bar/ --tagging 'TagSet=[{Key=colour,Value=blue}]
An error occurred (NoSuchKey) when calling the PutObjectTagging operation: The specified key does not exist.
```

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no concept of a directory in S3. Here is a **crude way** of achieving what you want. Other posters may have a better solution. The following solution first gets all the objects in the folder and then calls `put-object-tagging` for each one of them. **Note**: I didn't test this solution.

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket mybucket --query 'Contents[].{Key:Key}' 
    --output text | grep foo/bar/ | xargs aws s3api put-object-tagging 
    --bucket mybucket --tagging 'TagSet=[{Key=colour,Value=blue}]' --key
```

Comment: This does work (I tested it). But you don't need that grep as the s3api list-objects command takes a --prefix argument. Like... `aws s3api list-objects --prefix foo/bar/ ...`

Comment: A general warning/heads up... `aws s3api put-object-tagging` deletes any existing tags on the objects when it writes its new ones.

Answer (score 15):

**helloV**'s answer is corrected (have tested it) but it's not a good solution if the bucket is big, aws will take time to scan the whole bucket. Here is my solution

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket mybucket --query 'Contents[].{Key:Key}' --prefix foo/bar --output text | xargs -n 1 aws s3api put-object-tagging  --bucket mybucket --tagging 'TagSet=[{Key=colour,Value=blue}]' --key
```

The command has 2 parts:

1. List all the object in prefix of bucket and output to text
2. Use `xargs -n 1` to loop each of the result and tag it.

Comment: This worked nicely for me in a bucket with ~9000 objects

Comment: s3api list-objects with `--query` returns "None" for empty buckets, causing an `aws: error: argument --key: expected one argument` error. Was able to work around this with `aws s3api list-objects --bucket mybucket --prefix foo/bar --output json | jq '.Contents[] | .Key' | xargs -rn 1 aws s3api put-object-tagging  --bucket mybucket --tagging 'TagSet=[{Key=colour,Value=blue}]' --key`

Used jq to parse and added the -r flag to xargs.

Comment: use xargs -P 15 to go faster, that will make 15 processes to request them. Makes large buckets go much faster

Comment: See https://sykes.technology/blog/2022/04/27/Speed-Up-AWS-CLI-commands/ to speed up the command some more

Answer (score 6):

**Calvin Duy Canh Tran** 's answer might return error for filename with spaces, in the command below, I added an -I flag for `xargs` to replace the argument "targetobject" with standard input.

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket mybucket --query 'Contents[].{Key:Key}' --prefix testfolder/  --output text | xargs -n 1 -I targetobject aws s3api put-object-tagging --bucket mybucket --tagging 'TagSet=[{Key=colour,Value=blue}]' --key targetobject
```