# How to add tags to S3 objects using wildcard matching

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I want to tag s3 objects based on wildcard matching.  I used the following code to add the tags but It looks for specific key.  I tried to use --exclude and --include properties here but it didnt work.

```
aws s3api put-object-tagging --bucket test-bucket --key data/04-02-22/success --tagging "{\"TagSet\": [{\"Key\": \"department\", \"Value\": \"accounting\"}]}"
```

I have the following folder structure and I want to add tags to only the pdf which is present inside the success folder.any ideas? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS S3 cli - tag all objects within a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45676862/aws-s3-cli-tag-all-objects-within-a-directory)

Comment: Looks like it.  Let me try and update here. thank you !